# Mark tests explicit in SpecFlow

Tags: specflow

Is there a way to mark a Specflow test with an "Explicit" attribute? I am aware that a test can be marked with the "Ignore" attribute via the use of the special tag @ignore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe.

If you look at the generated xxx.feature.cs, you will see that it is defined as

```
public partial class xxx{...
```

So you can add another file to your project `xxx.partial.cs` that contains the other part of your partial definition.

*And that's the end of what I know, now for you might be able to do.*

In theory you could use the partial class definition and modify it, to make it abstract. Then you could add a derived class where you override the test in question, this would have to be a `new` as we can't use `virtual` in the xxx, and add your `[Explicit]` there.

I have no idea if this will work. You could have all sorts of issues with the abstract not taking, or the test attributes disappearing on the derived class, etc. But maybe it might get you going.

P.S. I'm also not sure this is anything near to good practice. :-)

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks for responding and +1 for creativity ;)

Comment: I was able to create a partial class and mark the entire fixture as explicit. Both the NUnit GUI and Resharper's test explorer honor the attribute, which is awesome. Visual Studio 2012's test explorer does not seem to honor it unfortunately, but that's the fault of Visual Studio and not your suggestion.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't acknowledge the existence of the Explicit attribute, so I guess that means it's working as designed...

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do this.

For scenario `Test Scenario` in file `xxx.feature.cs` there is a method `TestScenario()`. You can just mark it as `[Explicit]`.

Comment: Nope, editing generated code is not a good idea. Yes, you can do that, but your change will be overridden during the code generation on build action.